# How can i achieve this in android.(Encircled in the image)

Tags: android, progress-bar

[image]
I want to show order status in my app. I am stuck in this think like how to show the order status. Can anybody guide me through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a view that looks like a circle indicator:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/indic" />
```

drawable/inidic.xml:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="..."
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="COLOR" />
</shape>
```